# Javascript Fade Into New Image When Clicked

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow, fade

Right now I have a code to switch between two images when clicking text, but I'd like to create a function where I can click on the image itself and it fades into the next one, and be able to do this with more than two images. Also the images I want to use vary in width and height, but all have a max height and width of 600px. Here's my current code:

HTML:

```
<div id="cf2" class="shadow">
<img class="bottom" src="/images/Cirques.jpg" />
<img class="top" src="/images/Clown%20Fish.jpg" />
</div>
<p id="cf_onclick">Click me to toggle</p>
```

CSS:

```
#cf2 {
    position:relative;
    height:281px;
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#cf2 img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf2 img.transparent {
    opacity:0;
}
#cf_onclick {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cf_onclick").click(function() {
        $("#cf2 img.top").toggleClass("transparent");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will work for multiple images:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.nextOrFirst = function (selector) {
        var next = this.next(selector);
        return (next.length) ? next : this.prevAll(selector).last();
    };
    $("#cf2 img").click(function() {
        $(this)
        .removeClass('visible')
        .nextOrFirst()
        .addClass('visible');
    });
});
```

```css
#cf2 {
    position:relative;
    height:281px;
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#cf2 img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    max-height: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf2 img.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cf2" class="shadow">
    <img class="visible" src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" alt="1"/>
    <img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-45891755,width-640,resizemode-4/nasas-images-of-most-remarkable-events-you-cant-miss.jpg" alt="2"/>
    <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/11/03/article-2486855-192ACC5200000578-958_964x682.jpg" alt="3"/>
    <img src="http://mstatic.mit.edu/nom150/items/199-HybridImage.jpg" alt="4"/>
</div>
```

Instead of having an `.invisible` class, I used a `.visible` class, which also has a `z-index` of `1`, greater than that of the default images. So the image that has that class, will be visible, while the others will have `opacity: 0` by default.

I also extended the `jQuery` object to have a `nextOrFirst` method (which I stole from [here](http://www.mattvanandel.com/999/jquery-nextorfirst-function-guarantees-a-selection/)), so that when the visible image is the last one of the images in the stack, the next one will be the first. So now, the order of the images, as they appear, goes from top to bottom.

I decided to do it like this in order to keep your CSS transitions, but you can also use jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods.

Comment: For some reason the code is working when I put it into jsfiddle, but not when I put it in my actual file in dreamweaver. Is there a specific tag I need to use for the script you provided? Right now im putting it in a <script language="javascript"> tag...

Comment: Hmm, well, the code is alreadty wrapped around a `$(document).ready`, so you should be able to place it anywhere as long as it's inside of that. If it's not inside in your code, then the script tag must be placed after the `cf2` DIV.
Did you also change the CSS? Notice how I changed some of your CSS rules, so you can copy and paste what I have in here into your CSS, just to make sure. I also made changes to the <img> tags, don't forget to add a `visible` class to the image at the top of the insides of the DIV. The rest should have no classes (or at least not that one).

Comment: Got it! I just had to place it after the cf2 DIV. My apologies again, learning new things everyday about javascript! Can't thank you enough for all of your help :)

Comment: Oh, alright, don't worry. JavaScript is fun! Good luck on your journey. It's nothing, you're welcome :)

Comment: Now that I've got everything plugged in, whenever you click in the empty space next to an image, another one appears but it becomes very glitchy. Do you have any clue why this could be? Doesn't seem to have that problem in your code snippet...

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `#cf2 img` to selector initiating `click` event

```
$("#cf_onclick, #cf2 img")
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var n = -1 
  , imgs = $("#cf2 img")
  , fx = function(i, el) {
      return (el || imgs.eq(i)).fadeToggle(1000);
    };
  
  $("#cf_onclick, #cf2 img").click(function() {

    if (n === (-imgs.length)) {
      fx(n);
      n = -1;
      fx(null, imgs);
    } else {
      fx(n);
      --n
    };
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
#cf2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 281px;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#cf2 img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#cf_onclick {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="cf2" class="shadow">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats" />
  <img class="top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/technics" />
  <img class="top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/nature" />
  <img class="top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/animals" />
</div>
<p id="cf_onclick">Click me to toggle</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however it's still not working for me. I'm quite new to javascript so this is where a lot of the confusion lies. I'm beginning to think the code just needs re-written? I've tried searching all over but it's difficult to find what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cf_onclick").click(function() {
    var current = $("#cf2 img.top").removeClass('top');

    var next = current.next();
    next = next.length ? next : current.siblings().first();
    next.addClass('top');
  });
});
```

```css
#cf2 {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf2 img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf2 img.top {
  opacity: 1;
}

#cf_onclick {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="cf_onclick">Click me to toggle</p>
<div id="cf2" class="shadow">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/google/chrome/256/Google-Chrome-icon.png" />
    <img class="top" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/kyo-tux/aeon/256/Apps-Safari-icon.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Same code can be found in [this blog](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg2 "One image to another, when a button is pressed (transitions)")